# How to disable or ignore code if input is null in scss

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, null, undefined

I have code in my _dip.scss file like that :

```
#g-dip {
    @if $dip-background-style == 'bg-color' {
        background: $dip-bg-color;
    }
}
```

it's make background color with selected color from color input field if color option enabled. If no color selected from color input field in color mode, then it's make css code like that :

```
background: false;
```

How to disable

```
background: $dip-bg-color;
```

code if color mode enabled but no color selected from color input field?

I mean i want to remove or exclude the `background: $dip-bg-color;` code  if `$dip-background-style` enabled but `$dip-bg-color` is not defined from color input field.

I used that :

```
#g-dip {
    @mixin color {
    background: $dip-bg-color;
    }
    
    @if $dip-background-style == 'bg-color' {
            @include color;
    @if $dip-bg-color == 'false' {
        background: #ff0000;
        }   
    }
}
```

This is adding second line to after `background:false;` that making background color red when color is undefined.

```
    background: false;
    background: #f00;
```

I want to results like this :

If Background Color Mode($dip-background-style=bg-color) Enabled + Color Selected($dip-bg-color=Defined) =

```
background:$dip-bg-color;
```

If Background Color Mode($dip-background-style=bg-color) Enabled + **No Color Selected($dip-bg-color=Undefined or Null or False)** =

```
Nothing to do for background
```

Sory for my bad Eglish.

Comment: try using JS or php. most of the times this things should be done through JS because in html css they can be easily modified from user side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding `@if $dip-bg-color` rule as parent.

Working way is :

```
@if $dip-bg-color {

   @if $dip-background-style == 'bg-color' {
        background: $dip-bg-color;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `$dip-bg-color` has value:

```
$dip-background-style: 'bg-color';
$dip-bg-color: false;

#g-dip {
    @if $dip-bg-color and $dip-background-style == 'bg-color' {
        background: $dip-bg-color;
    } @else {
        background: initial;
    }
}
```

Comment: So set it to `background: initial` or exclude `@else` part completely